# Users and groups icon not showing

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, users, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups? (GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui)

I'm trying to setup virtualbox in my ubuntu 11.10 install but I can't find the icon for users and groups to change the settings and modify usb access for my virtual machine ....
Any help?