# How to manage users and groups using GUI?

Tags: gui, users, user-management

Just switched from 10.04 to 11.10. I'm wondering about the limited options in the GUI for managing users and groups. Where is the old GUI to change groups, id's, etc. I know that I can do this from cli, that's no problem. But I want this comfortable GUI back.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Gnome System Tools for 11.10 & later Ubuntu versions

The old Users and Groups GUI is available by installing from Software Center the *gnome-system-tools* package

[image]

or from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Search in Dash:

[image]

Click and it will run the Users and Groups applet:

[image]

Comment: `users-admin` from command line

Answer (score 45):

*This answer was merged from a question about how to make a user an administrator; while it does answer this more general question, making administrators is its focus.*

### Being An Administrator Consists of (Specific) Group Membership

Before actually managing users and groups, if you want to make one or more users administrators, you should know *what* it means to be an administrator in Ubuntu.

An administrator can run commands as [`root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like), in two ways:

- [With `sudo`.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)
- [With PolicyKit.](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) (But default, PolicyKit is not present on Ubuntu Server systems.)

This power is conferred to users by membership in the appropriate group.

- In Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier, administrators are members of the `admin` group.
- In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and later, administrators are members of the `sudo` group.

There are a couple complexities:

- The `sudo` group exists in 11.10 and earlier, it's just not used (by default).
- The `admin` group doesn't exist on a freshly installed 12.04 system, but it continues to exist (and its members continue to have administrative abilities) on Ubuntu 12.04 systems upgraded from previous releases.

Therefore, here are some reasonable guidelines for how to make a user an administrator in Ubuntu:

- If you're running Ubuntu 11.10 or earlier, just put the user in the `admin` group.
- If you're running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (or later), put the user in the `sudo` group, and *if the `admin` group exists, put the user there too*.

---

***You have a few options for managing users and groups.***

## Install and Run the Classic "Users and Groups" Utility

You'll perhaps be happy to hear that (as [John S Gruber](https://askubuntu.com/users/63886/john-s-gruber) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/174091/22949)) *the old GUI utility for managing users and groups still exists, though you may have to install the package that provides it*. I'm talking about the utility that was invoked in menu-driven interfaces via **System** > **Administration** > **Users and Groups**.

This classic utility is provided by the [gnome-system-tools [image: Install gnome-system-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-system-tools) package, which you can install in the Software Center by clicking that link, or in the Terminal by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

The name of the **Users and Groups** utility is [`users-admin`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/users-admin.1.html), so you can find it normally in your graphical interface, or you can run it manually with that name. That is, here are some ways to run the utility once it's installed:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Type `users-admin`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Type `users-admin`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In Unity, start to type `users and groups`. So long as `gnome-system-tools` is installed, the **Users and Groups** utility will come up.
- If you use a desktop environment that has menus, find **Users and Groups** in the **Administration**, **System Tools**, or **Preferences** menu.

[image: Users Settings window (users-admin in Ubuntu 12.04)]

But **don't** run `sudo user-admin`, or even `gksu/gksudo/kdesudo users-admin`. `users-admin` will actually [not work when run as `root`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-tools/+bug/685215). (It is designed to use [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html) rather than [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) to gain the necessary privileges to create and modify users and groups on the system.)

[image: users-admin authenticating via PolicyKit]

On some Ubuntu [variants](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives), such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), `users-admin` is already installed and is the standard way to manage users and groups.

## Use GNOME Control Center to Manage Users and Groups

The new, standard way to manage users and groups is with the GNOME Control Center, accessible from the session menu. Click the gear icon in the top panel (at the upper-right corner of the screen), and click **System Settings...**.

[image: indicator-session menu showing "System Settings..." item, for opening GNOME Control Center]

In **System Settings** (also called the **GNOME Control Center**), click **User Accounts** (it's near the bottom, in the "System" category).

[image: System Settings (GNOME Control Center), showing mouse pointer over "User Accounts"]

You can then manage users, including what groups they're members of, with this part of the GNOME Control Center.

[image: User Accounts window of GNOME Control Center]

## Use Command-Line Utilities

If you...

- are running Ubuntu Server, or some other Ubuntu system with no GUI, or
- just prefer to use command-line utilities, or
- are running some weird desktop environment that doesn't come with a graphical utility to manage users and groups

...then you can manage users and groups from the command-line.

The recommended utility for adding a user from the command-line (in Ubuntu, and also in Debian and other Debian-based OSes) is [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/adduser.8.html). The simplest way to use it is just to run:

```
sudo adduser --add_extra_groups username
```

- You may be prompted for *your* password first (that's [how `sudo` works](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Usage)).
- Then you're asked a series of questions. Besides their real name and password, if you don't have an answer to any of the questions, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- The user is made a member of the default groups for user accounts that *do* represent real human beings, but *do not* have administrative powers.

[image: screenshot showing adduser, run in a desktop environment that doesn't provide user management utilities of its own]
<sup>[Click here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1139876/) to read as text.</sup>

To make a user an administrator from the command-line, just add them to the appropriate group. [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/usermod.8.html) is an excellent utility for this purpose. The `-G` flag means you're specifying one or more new groups, and the `-a` flag means you're *adding* these to whatever groups the user is already a member of, rather than *replacing* the old list of groups with a new one.

Depending on what version of Ubuntu you're running (as detailed above), use one or both of these commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo username
```

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin username
```

Comment: I've created an account to upvote your answer. You made my life much easier (using a fork of ubuntu, Mint)

Comment: Question on this: "You can then manage users, including what groups they're members of, with this part of the GNOME Control Center." - I could not find a way to use the standard Ubuntu `User accounts` application to add a group to a user. Do you know how? I was able to do it only using `users-admin` tool.

Answer (score 12):

You can edit users by going under System Settings (either search for it in the Dash, or select it as the first entry under the power cog) and selecting User Accounts.

[image: System Settings screenshot with User Accounts highlighted]

Alternatively, you may search the Ubuntu Software Center or use `apt-get` to install the `gnome-system-tools` package, then run `users-admin` afterwards to get to working with groups ([source](http://techspear.com/2011/09/how-to-access-user-groups-in-ubuntu-11-10/)).

Comment: That "User Accounts" seems so limited. I need to add an account to a user-group. There existed "Users and Groups" before. I may do this job in terminal, but wanted to know where the menu is.

Comment: @Chang AFAIK that menu was taken out of the default install. But now that I know better what you're looking for, I did a quick search and updated my answer. Let me know if this looks more like what you want.

Comment: I don't know how limited this new "User Accounts" Ubuntu GUI is (I'm still using 10.10), but I can understand why they removed Gnome's "Users and Groups": the groups listed in the checkboxes (in Advanced Settings) are *hardcoded* and terribly outdated. Not to mention the selection for an "Administrator User" is quite different from Ubuntu's defaults for the first user.

Comment: The "user accounts" is just plain WRONG ubuntu has dumbed down the settings pannel way to far so users wont hurt them selves.  If they are going to make a control pannel for dummies they need to add in a switch or other simple method for power users to get access to the normal controls with out having to install 100 normal and expected default tools

Comment: @Kendrick AFAIK the GNOME project should be blamed, not Ubuntu. Ubuntu just inherits whatever GNOME decides upstream, with a few exceptions. This is just one of the changes that was necessary to make the transition to GNOME 3.

Comment: I thought unity was ubuntu's own special twist on gnome.

Comment: @Kendrick Unity is an alternative shell for GNOME 3, which is Ubuntu's underlying desktop environment. It's just a replacement for GNOME Shell, not the whole GNOME system.

Answer (score 1):

For adding and deleting standard and administrative users I'd recommend that you use the standard tool Alex mentioned in [his helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/174070/22949). You will need to unlock the program and then click on the "+" on the bottom left. You can also administer passwords with this tool.

If you need to add groups or add users to groups you can install the [gnome-system-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-system-tools) (Cross-platform configuration utilities for GNOME) package.

After adding that you can find the additional settings by searching the `dash` for `Users and Groups`

Answer (score -1):

You can add both standard and administrator users using the `settings->user accounts` pane. You can set the password after the account has been added.

If you need more fine-grained control over which groups an account is in you will need to use the `usermod` program.