# How to set user rights in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, users, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups? (GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui)

I remember having a list of options of what a user can do in previous versions. For example, I want a standard user to be able to mount disks. How can that be done in Oneiric Ocelot?

[Here](http://library.gnome.org/users/users-admin/stable/tool-usage.html.en) is a link to documentation of what was used previously.

Comment: Are you saying standard users can't mount disks in Oneiric?

Comment: @mikewhatever For me, they can't.

Answer (score 3):

By installing [gnome-system-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-system-tools) [image: Install gnome-system-tools] we gain access to **Users and Groups** that we used for this purpose in previous releases. We can call this application either from the Dash (*Users and Groups*) or in a terminal by

```
users-admin
```