# Where's admin tools gone in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, users, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups? (GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui)

In 11.10, with Unity, I do not see all the admin tools. Especially, I want to access "Users and Groups" tool. Where is it? Should I install it? How can I access all the admin tools that were with the previous Ubuntu versions, in general?