# Can't see any USB device in VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox

In Ubuntu 11.10 , i'm unable to see any USB device in VirtualBox , although i had the ext package installed , which is downloaded from oracle's site today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most usual cause of this problem is that you have not added your user to the vboxusers group.

Note that gnome 3 (what 11.10 uses) has removed the ability to add groups from their user management applet. See this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui/66727#66727) to use the old GUI tool or use the command line.

You will need to log-ou and log-in again to be able to use USB under VirtualBox.

Comment: did a `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER` , solved the problem , kudos for you guys ;-P

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem but I got the solution and it worked,
just type this command

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

For further information follow the link

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-linux-host