# How do I fine-tune user privileges?

Tags: 11.10, users, privileges

In previous versions of Ubuntu, I was able to fine-tune user privileges easily via a tool. However, the present version apparently only allows two levels: standard or administrator. How do I e.g. give a standard user rights to connect to wireless networks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage users and groups? (GUI)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-gui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `gnome-system-tools` package from the Ubuntu Software Centre (or use

`sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`

in a terminal). This will install the 'old' users and groups tool.

To run it, search for 'admin' or 'user' in the Unity dash and choose "Users and Groups". Alternatively, you can run 'users-admin' in a terminal.