# Tweaking User privileges Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, administration, system-settings

I would like to fine tune user privileges  after reviewing default available privileges for a standard user.

Is there a way to fine tune it? I was using 10.04 and 10.10 until now and I could not find advanced settings in Users screen in 12.04.

I saw an older question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75455/how-do-i-fine-tune-user-privileges)  and want to confirm if this is still the right way for 12.04 or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `gnome-system-tools` with this command

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

or using the link [gnome-system-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-system-tools) [image: Install gnome-system-tools]

and then try using the old fried `users-admin`

Comment: @Jamess You can [accept the answer](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did that and upvoted as well . I validated only after the comment

Answer (score 1):

Still `users-admin` is the tool to do that.