# How to enable wireless network for standard users?

Tags: wireless, internet, users

how can I allow standard users to connect to wireless network without administrator password?
It's simple question. I need any positive answer.

Comment: Do you need standard users to be able to configure new wireless networks or just access existing ones?  If it's the latter have you tried checking `Available to all users` at the bottom of the wireless network configuration window in the Network-Manager GUI?

Answer (score 9):

To allow change of wifi-connection without admin password create new file

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla
```

with the following content:

```
[Enable NetworkManager]
Identity=unix-group:netdev
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Yeap.This worked for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: you need to replace ```netdev``` with the actual group of the user.

Comment: Another point for your code.

Answer (score 5):

To make a wireless network available to all users we need to make shure that all users have the privilege to *"Connect to wireless and ethernet networks"*. You can set this from **Users and Groups** from the package [gnome-system-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-system-tools) [image: Install gnome-system-tools]

(see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)).

To make a wireless network available to all users we also need to tick the box *"Available to all users"* on the bottom left side of *Edit connections -> Wireless -> Edit*:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to allow them connecting to wireless network that  i hadn't created in list of network connections.For example if my standard user finds himself in area where he can connect to network that is new for my laptop.

Comment: On my installation I had to also add the users to the _netdev_ group. Without creating a networking connection succeeded but establishing failed.

Answer (score 3):

To expound on Takkat's answer, to give a standard user permission to connect to any wireless network (even as yet unknown ones):

1. Install gnome-system-tools, e.g. `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`
2. Launch the program "Users and Groups".
3. Select the user, click "Advanced Settings" then the "User Privleges" tab.
4. Check "Connect to wireless and ethernet networks", then click save.

Comment: That is not sufficient to e.g. create a new Wifi connection as Guest on 16.04.

Comment: The question didn't ask about Guest users, but standard users, and it works for standard users