# 'sudo' not working after changing the permissions of '/usr' directory

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, sudo, gksu

Recently I had to change the folder permissions of `/usr` folder. Now the whole `sudo` is not working. If I try to update my system using this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following message:

```
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

So I tried to change the folder permissions by opening Nautilus as root by using this command

```
gksudo nautilus
```

But nothing happened. Nautilus didn't open. This is an emergency as the whole of `sudo` is not working. when I tried searching the solution from Google many suggested re-installation. I don't prefer re-installation. so is there any other solution?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidently-run-command-chmod

Comment: Please include HOW you changed permissions on `/usr`. Default perms on `sudoers.so` are `644`, owned by `root:root`

Comment: "I had to change the folder permissions of /usr folder." Care to give us the reason? I am interested since I do not believe there is one that has someone messing with the permissions of /usr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two mechanisms set up in Ubuntu for performing administrative tasks. [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) is one of them, and it and its graphical frontends (like [`gksu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html) and [`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html)) are not going to work until you fix the permissions problem.

The other mechanism is [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html). Depending on exactly what you have done to your file permissions, it's likely that you can still recover using PolicyKit to run commands as `root`.

The [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) command will run any (nongraphical) command as `root` (provided that the user invoking it is an administrator on the system). `pkexec` is capable of running graphical commands (like `nautilus`) as `root`, too, but this is quite nontrivial, as you have to set up configuration files for them describing how they are supposed to be run and what they are supposed to be allowed to do. Therefore, you're best off using the command-line to fix this problem...at least to the point where `sudo` works again. (Then you can run `gksu nautilus` to get a `root` file browser, if you're more comfortable using that to edit file permissions recursively.)

I don't know exactly what you did to your permissions, so it's hard for me to give you a specific `pkexec` command to run, to fix the problem. But you can rectify the specific problem that `sudo` is currently complaining about. It says:

```
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
```

So remove `group` and `other` write permissions (while not modifying `owner` write permissions) for that file:

```
pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Then you can see if `sudo` works (by running some innocuous command like `sudo ls`).

If you need to perform other operations on file permissions from the command-line with `chmod`, see [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chmod.1.html).

(By the way, [here's another, related situation where it's handy to know about `pkexec`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-anderror-and-not-allowi).)

If you have trouble getting `pkexec` to work for this, please feel free to comment here, and I'll try to render further assistance. **But you should know that even if this method does not work, you shouldn't have to reinstall Ubuntu.**

**Instead, you can fix the problem from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD or live USB system, because the live system will be functioning--`sudo` will work on it--and you can mount your Ubuntu partition and change the permissions that way.**

**Or as a third option** (as [forestpiskie](https://askubuntu.com/users/2018/forestpiskie) has [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/143562/22949))**, you could use [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).**

Comment: Thank you! the pkexec command did the work and sudo is working again,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would try booting into recovery mode and setting the permissions back to what they were.

Reboot - choose second item from menu to get to recovery mode.

> recently I had to change the folder permissions of /usr folder

What asked you to change permissions of the whole /usr folder?

Comment: "setting permission back to what they were" - I have changed them and do not know what they were!!

Answer (score 0):

install **Users And Groups** using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)
go to **Manage Groups**
and add you to `sudo` group

Comment: This will not help. The problem isn't that the original poster is not in the `sudo` group. The problem is that `sudo` refuses to work for any user, because it sees that it is itself set up insecurely (with some of its own files accessible by all users).