# color seems unaligned since fixed login loop, other graphics changed (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: unity, themes, colors

after I fixed my previous problem ([login loop ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314259/login-loop-ubuntu-12-04)), my graphics (only in Unity afaik) been changed. Pictures and other media don't have any problem with their display, so it isn't a problem of my driver or videocard (It functioned fine before said login loop)

When I use the Radiance theme, the color in the top bar of Unity seem very unaligned. The black letters are surrounded with thin lines of other (mixed) colors (primarily yellow, green and blue). This disappears in other themes.

However in all themes, the side bar of Unity (with all shortcuts) remains black. I believe most, shortcuts still have their original color scheme, but the ones related to Ubuntu itself also got a black background (like the dash; workspace; trash; hard disk and dvd disk buttons).

The alt+tab screen itself also got changed to a more old windows look (xp or 2003).

Maybe relevant is that I get a grey screen just after login, which I didn't get before this problem arose.

Can anyone help with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. Apparently I accidentally used Ubuntu in its 2D mode, which caused the distortions and other problems. Turning it to the normal mode in the login screen solved the problem!