# 14.04 Log-in screen loops when trying to log in to any account

Tags: 14.04, login, tty

Whenever I try to log in to any account my 14.04 PC, the log-in screen returns to the log-in screen as soon as I log in. It flashes for a second, like it's going to go to the desktop, but then it just goes back to the log-in. I can get in to my tty terminals but I don't know what to do there. I tried the instructions given here, ([login loop ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314259/login-loop-ubuntu-12-04)) after I type in the "mv ~.Xauthority..." command, I get this message: "mv: cannot stat '~.Xauthority': No such file or directory". I don't have any idea on how to solve it, and I haven't been able to use my PC at all for the past week as a result. I would very much appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23232/discussion-on-question-by-grapes234-14-04-log-in-screen-loops-when-trying-to-log).

Comment: @Mitch I see where the chat is now.  Can I ask one thing, if I am helping someone with a 1 reputation, how are they supposed to chat there if the requirements are 20?  

`Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while you're at it, check out the FAQ!`

Answer (score 0):

I found some good step by step driver installation steps.  On this link in the first answer posted is some steps that you should follow to reinstall your ATI drivers.

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Feel free to ask me questions still, and I will definitely help you out as much as I can.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks. I'll try this when I get home and get back to you on it. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: These steps look to involve going to the AMD website. How can I do that from the terminal?

Comment: Try the NOTE: part.  Where it shows doing the CTRL+ALT+F1, then after logging in do `sudo aticonfig --uninstall` then after it uninstalls the driver, type in `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot it.  It should be able to come up without the driver installed, and you should be able to log in.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll try that now.

Comment: It says "sudo: ati: command not found"

Comment: I typed it in wrong.

Comment: Okay, now I typed it in correctly, and it's saying "sudo: aticonfig: command not found"

Comment: See if you can access the chat that Mitch above created for us.