# Problem using “sudo su” command

Tags: root

I can't login as root, this is what happens:

```
gladiss@gladiss-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo su
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I've tried all commands suggested in similar threads. Nothing helped.
Maybe cause this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please output the result of `ll /usr/lib/sudo/`? Also about what file is that image?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['sudo' not working after changing the permissions of '/usr' directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143554/sudo-not-working-after-changing-the-permissions-of-usr-directory)

Comment: is that account an admin account or is it a guest like account?

Comment: whenever you do get back on as root, do a `sudo passwd` as root and change it's password to something you know. That way you can just do a `su` to login as root.

Comment: @janos I'm curious - what did that edit accomplish?

Comment: @janos and why bump this years-old question just for that? (I'm asking because you have been making minor edits to a lot of old questions lately)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "sudo -i" to login as root.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner

It seems the file `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` has the wrong permissions. It should be writable only by the owner, but apparently that's not the case. Confirm the permission bits shown by:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

The integrity of the `sudoers.so` library is critical for the security of the system, that's why all `sudo` commands are automatically rejected, as a safety feature.

To fix the permissions you would have to become `root`, one way or another. Do you have a root password? Probably not. Start the system in rescue mode, and boot a live CD and mount your disk, fix the permissions and reboot.

Perhaps even more important is to find out how this happened. Have you been hacked?