# How to grant standard users access to disk partitions and flash storage?

Tags: permissions

I have a partition that I need standard users (not administrators)to have read/write access to. However, this partition does not even appear to them as it does to me as an administrator. How can I make it so that standard users can read/write to this partition? It would be nice if they could have the ability to mount it if needed.

I have the same problem with removable media - if I have a flash card in the computer, the standard users cannot see this storage media.

Comment: Do you require access to the raw partition or to the filesystem on it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Unity dash, and type Users and Groups.  When the window opens, click on the desired user, and then the Advanced Settings Tab

[image]

and then click on the User Privileges tab, and choose the options that you want.

[image]

Comment: How do we do this in 13.04?

Comment: Take a look at [How to manage users and groups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)