# How do I addusers with passwords and assign them to groups and make them administrators?

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)

What happened to the user and groups management GUI applications that worked so well in 10.04?  It looks like all of this has moved back to CLI?!