# How do I add the "user and groups" application?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)

I once installed this (gnome thing?) wich gave me an easy access to users groups and advanced settings. But now after reinstalling ubuntu 12.04 I can´t find the command line anymore. Does anyone know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably talking about Gnome System Tools, is a set of tools manage your system.  It includes, Users and groups, Date and time, Network configuration, and others.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```