# Volume control not working on one account

Tags: 12.04, sound, acer, volume-control, speakers

I am getting sound out of my speakers but, the volume control is not working and in the sound settings there is nothing listed in play sound through and test sound is not working.  I am only having this problem on one account, it seems to work fine on other accounts.  I am running 12.04 on a Acer Aspire 4743Z-4861.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following (one after the other):

- make sure the affected user is **not** in the `audio` [group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups), then reboot.
- rename (or delete) the hidden directory `~/.pulse` for removing erroneous user settings from the affected account, then log out and back in.
- Unlikely cause, but if present remove external audio devices (e.g. earphones), then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. In my case the cause was the fact that my home is a symlink to a ntfs directory.

Im not shure why it caused the problem, but i solved it changing my $HOME variable to a place with a ext4 file system.

I hope it helps.