# Is there a GUI to `visudo`?

Tags: software-recommendation, sudo, gui, visudo

Quite simply, is there a GUI to `visudo` I can recommend to other users, and use for myself? I have to set up a system where over 50 users have different sudo privileges and I need to juggle them all.

Comment: This still works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups  ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind It does, but not when I an trying to juggle more complex permissions.

Comment: GUI and more complex? If complex I'd use command line (I would script something that adds the lines you need to visudo). Problem with GUI is that is will always depend on you inserting a user name 1st... so you will have to do this for all users manually.

Comment: @Rinzwind Can you give a link to such a script? I think that users seeking to edit `sudoers` can be directed to this question for a GUI.

Comment: sure :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script All you need is a tmp file that holds the lines you need and you can use that script to create a new visudo.

Comment: @Rinzwind It's more for one-time management I need to offer to a non-Linux-oriented school employee... :)

Answer (score -2):

1- "The configuration file for sudo is /etc/sudoers. It should always be edited with the visudo command. visudo locks the sudoers file, saves edits to a temporary file, and checks that file's grammar before copying it to /etc/sudoers."

2- Automatic repetitive work is generally best done via a script, not a GUI.

Comment: You are correct, but I need to provide the program to non-computer-oriented school staff.

Comment: Are you the one who will change the sudoers file, or the owner of each computer? Only root is allowed to change the file.

Comment: I am not the one modifying. The owner will. They can elevate already.

Comment: I dont think your answer answers the question in any way