# Gnome 2 style user account settings (how to edit user accounts in Unity)

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)

Back in Gnome 2 there was a very useful user account editing gui tool whereby I could easily add or edit a user to a group. For example, I could give a standard user access to something that they hadn't installed or don't have default access too, such as Me-TV. How do I do this in Gnome 3 / Unity?

I am not allowed to create the tag "edit user accounts" or similar and there isn't anything similar existing, strangely. I'm guessing there is a totally different way to edit user accounts or no one bothers - perhaps no one shares PCs anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the original GUI tool for doing this.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Not too sure why they removed it, but it's certainly still available for install.