# How to log in after logout in L/UBUNTU live persistent usb?

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb, login-screen, logout, persistence

I have created a persistent live usb of Lubuntu 12.10 on a 16 GB flash pendrive with a 4GB space for persistency.

It basically works like an installation, as new programs can be installed and new settings and customizations added and remembered. Except that the username in terminal is lubuntu and at boot/startup am not asked for a password and the system starts without passing through the logging stage.

But there is a problem if one (e.g. in order to initiate certains settings) is logging out  instead of restarting/rebooting: the logging screen appears and contains **initially** no name and no space for password, and there's no login button: but if i click or press enter the name of user is "Other" and space for pass and login button appear. The name of the user cannot be changed (i guess there's no real user registered) and login doesn't work without password entered. Also, the passwords "ubuntu" or "lubuntu" are reported as incorrect.

Is there a way of using logout-and-in or should this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there is a way to have a consistent user:

1. Boot up the live USB again and create a new user account. You want it to be an administrator. Set the password, name, etcetera.
2. Log out
3. Log in to the account you just created

To create new user you need gnome-system-tools (more detail on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/174384/47206)).

But this is not a complete solution: indeed it is possible to log back in after logout, **but only with the new/different user**. This is useful in persistent USB in order to avoid restarting the computer after having logged out for some reason. Without a new user it was not possible to log in back at all  without restart. After creating a new user, one can log in with that new user, **but not with the initial "live" one**.

So, the problem is not completely solved, **the initial user (here called "lubuntu") cannot log back in without reboot**.

Comment: @vasa1: I don't know how to add new user from CLI. (the answer does not tell how to add the new user so i edited to add an info on that, according to what i was able to find out. I do not remember if in Lubuntu "Users and Groups" from gnome-system-tools is included by default or not.)

Comment: @vasa1: indeed it does: that is, it creates a new user. this is useful  in persistent USB in order to avoid having to restart the computer after having logged out for some reason. without a new user i was not able to log back in without restart. after creating a new user, one can log in with that new user, but not with the initial "live" one, so, the problem is not solved, **the initial user (here called "lubuntu") cannot log back in without reboot**. maybe i should re-edit the answer to add this info

Answer (score 4):

In 14.04 the username is ubuntu and the password is blank.

Comment: Thnx it worked for me :p

Answer (score 2):

go to console ctrl+alt+f1 if you're on a netbook or another funky keyboard you might have to press 'Fn' to activate the F buttons

it is already logged in and as far as i can tell you can't log out

run passwd when it asks for CURRENT password press enter, that is, give it a blank password.

then enter a new password

finally use this new password to log in in x windows

Answer (score 1):

I've got it under lubuntu 14:04 beta2:

- Go to TTY1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- Type `sudo passwd lubuntu` (just `passwd` will not work because lubuntu ask you for the old password)
- Choose a new password
- Go back to the X session with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- choose *lubuntu* as a user and type in your new password

Welcome back!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Go to TTY1: Ctrl+Alt+F1
> Type sudo passwd lubuntu (just passwd will not work because lubuntu ask you for the old password)
> Choose a new password
> Go back to the X session with Alt+F7
> choose lubuntu as a user and type in your new password
> ```

Worked for me as well—on a lubuntu 14.04 live usb stick.

I'd added 'nm-applet' to the default applications in order to get the panel applet icon to appear in order to configure wi-fi and then needed to restart the session to activate it.

tnx

Answer (score 1):

I have 14.10 ...use lubuntu for the user and enter nothing for the password(don't even click in the password field) and click login.

However, if you log out your progs will be closed, instead use switch user and sign back in as the same user (lubuntu) as above. I'm also pretty sure I have done this in 15.10.

Note that there are 3 fields on the login screen, I don't know the purpose of the field with "Other.." as text. Ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with a ubuntu-mate live, and tried with 'ubuntu-mate' username and blank password in the lock screen, it worked.

Comment: yes, lubuntu (user) seemed to work last I tried...