# How do I add a user to sudoers file?

Tags: grub2, sudo

How to I add my username to the sudoers file?

On my ubuntu desktop, the sudoer file has only root.

so basically, I will just need to adduser to sudo file system. 
And I need to access to single user mode.

I know the easiest way to to just select recovery mode in grub by hold down left Shift when booting. Then Drop to root shell prompt.

But it is ready-only file system. I need to write myself to the file.

I know I have to select remount first, but where is it?

and any other way to add myself to sudo?

Comment: You have to write the command by hand. `mount -o rw,remount /` and be carefull what are you doing because you can screw up your system easily (as root).

Comment: it says,   mount: special device remout does not exist. since Ubuntu 12.10, remount menu is not there on recovery mnenu.

Comment: There is no remount menu. First boot from advanced options -> Recovery Mode and then select root. There you must give the command I wrote above. Also be careful with the syntax. It seems like you made a mistake with the command

Comment: I've answered your question based on the your wanting to add yourself to sudo. However, I am having difficulty trying to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I did the command under etc path. but the file sudoers  is still read-only.   as there is only root on sudoers path. How do I add my username to sudoers?

Comment: octioysgrabbus,  my desktop cant access sudo.  I try add to add my username to sudo by using single user mode. But I cant write myself to sudoers file.

Comment: Any member of **sudo** group can use `sudo`. If you have accidently deleted yourself from this take a look at my answer to this qusetion [How to recover root user](http://askubuntu.com/a/279310/107450)

Comment: Read this link, hope it helps.

[Debian user is not in the sudoers file][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101063/debian-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bit of a predicament you're in. If you've given your root account a password, `su` may allow you to elevate privileges and add your user to the group "sudo" or "admin".

If not, have you tried running a live CD? You should be able to mount your root partition from the Ubuntu live CD fairly easily, say to `/mnt/tmproot/`, and add this line somewhere in `/mnt/tmproot/etc/sudoers`:

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

where "username" is whatever your username is.

Answer (score 0):

If your user name is as an example `jlin`, you should be able to sudo, if you entered your name as the sudo user when you installed Ubuntu.

If you want to add another user or if your username did not install Ubuntu, then you must log in as that user who installed Ubuntu, enter `sudo -i` to get root prompt; and then enter this command `visudo`.

I usually add the users I want to have sudo access. You can also add a group to have sudo access. I prefer just adding the users. I added a space in between the following, so it would format better.

# User_Alias ADMINS = jsmith, mikem

dbadmin ALL=(ALL) ALL

You can also use this command (as root)

`sudo usermod -a -G sudo hduser`