# Share a Folder between two Local Users

Tags: permissions, users, file-sharing

I and my brother have User Accounts on this machine. I want to share the Documents directory with him.

Is there a **STRAIGHTFORWARD** way to do it?

I am not a power user so I am looking for a way to do this using nautilus, rather than a script or a way that requires creating symlinks.

I can download an application if i have to.

Last time I wanted to do this I just copied the contents to `/home` for both of us to use.

Something I can do in **System Settings** would be appreciated

Comment: Once you created the shared directory with the right permission, you can just access by `smb://127.0.0.1`

Comment: Is "Documents Director" the name of the folder or is Director the name of the folder that resides in your Documents folder? Why no symlink creation? It can be done by drag and drop.

Comment: why is that you do not want an easy way to do that ....

Comment: maybe i put the question in a wrong way.. but i want an easy way out.. methods already available give out scripts to achieve this.

Comment: @Achu i tried you method.. i get an error saying "unable to mount location, failed to mount windows share". am i missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are three steps to this process

**Step One:** Make your brother a member of your group.

Your group-name is same as your user-id. Say, if your user-ID is `akumar` your group name is also `akumar`. If your brother's ID is `bkumar`, then you want to make `bkumar` a member of the group `akumar`. See [How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups) for how to add your brother's user-ID to your group.

**Step Two:** Change the permission of the folder you want to share.

Open Nautilus. Right click on the folder you want to share. Go to permissions tab. look for the group permissions and change it into "Read and Write." Check the box for allowing the same permissions to the files and folders inside.

**Step Three:** Verify that your brother can create delete files in the shared folder.

Let your brother login to the computer. Open Nautilus. It will open to your brother's home folder. Navigate to your home folder and open the shared folder by:

click on **Computer** or **System Files** (depends on the version of Ubuntu) on the left panel.

Double click on **home** folder, double click on folder named **akumar** inside **home**.

Create a file in the folder. Delete the new file.

**Step Four: (optional)** Make a link of this folder to your brother's home folder.

while logged in as your brother, open another window of Nautilus next to the first one, by middle-click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left click. In your own home folder where the shared folder resides, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag the shared folder to your brother's home folder.

Hope this helps

Comment: Step 3: i cant navigate to my home folder /home/arun from my brother's account.

Comment: step1 , step2 completed as it is, me and my brother in same user group ___arun___ and i have changed the group permission to read and write.

Comment: @user68186 I think there is a step missing: make sure to log out after you made them members of a certain group?

Comment: Is there a solution through the terminal?

Comment: @becko each step can be done by command line on a terminal.  Even if you can't add an user to a new group without `sudo`, you can change the permission of files and folders you own.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Exactly what commands I need?

Answer (score 12):

```
sudo mkdir /shared
sudo chmod a+rw /shared
```

Now everyone can see and edit the **/shared** folder. Feel free putting files there and everyone will be able to access this folder and share files between users.

Comment: would "$sudo chmod g+w /shared"  be a better answer since it will be only the group (brothers) and not the parents?

Comment: @Andres - your solution will need more steps, like creating the group and adding several users to the group. I think my suggested solution is the quickest.

Comment: @Andres - anyhow, yours will work as well. Feel free writing an answer with it - If it's a working answer, I'll vote for it :)

Comment: this did not work. even I can't access the folder.

Comment: This give write permissions without read. And it is a privacy/security risk to just grant access to everyone. Using a group is much better.

Comment: Changed - added `+r`.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend the following solution:
- Create a group for sharing, just call it "shared".
- Add all users who should have access to the shared files to this group.
- Create a directory outside of users homes, e.g. /shared for shared files.
- Change group of this folder to the group for sharing and adjust group permissions.
- Set group sticky bit for this shared folder.

Advantages of this solution:
- Every file you copy into this folder automatically gets the shared group, so every user who is a member of this group can access these files without any additional effort.
- You still can have your private files outside this folder with your personal group which are not accessible by other users as long as they cannot get root and they cannot boot with another Linux OS. But keep in mind: If you want to have real privacy then you have to use encrypted folders/files.

I'm wondering why Linux distributions still have no common solution for this problem, because nearly everyone is concerned.