# Give VirtualBox access to specific users only

Tags: server, permissions

I have installed VirtualBox on an Ubuntu Server installation, and I have created a user on that server named `ram`.

I want to give access to VirtualBox and its programs and operations *only* to the root user and the user named `ram`.

What do I have to do to set this kind of restricted access for VirtualBox?

Comment: What do mean by a username ram?

Comment: @ptetteh227 I think my edits to their question to make it more readable will answer that.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, only superuser and members of `vboxusers` can use Vbox by default. You can add users to the vboxusers group with the following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

This will give that user permission to run VirtualBox machines.

Comment: Nice was wondering how this can be done!

Comment: It's probably the permissions of `/dev/vboxdrv` that matters, as this gives access to the kernel modules. This file is group writable and probably owned by `root.vboxusers` or similar.

Comment: I tried sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers ram but its not working. From ubuntu root users i have installed ubuntu inside virtualbox but when i logout and login to ram user and try opening virtualbox ... it does not show ubunut that is being installed in virtualbox

Comment: So you have a machine created and owned by root, which the user `ram` should have access to? In that case, this is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/455389/how-to-share-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-with-users-of-the-computer

Comment: The url which you send me did not work

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get any error messages? What did you actually do?

Comment: I simply trigger sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers ram command . It does not show any error messages either. for verification i logout and login to normal user and tried virtualbox again but it did not opened.