# How to permit only certain users to access and use virtualbox?

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, 18.04

I'm wondering if we can restrict the access and usage of Virtualbox only to specific users. I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04**. I've multiple accounts configured in my PC and I don't want the guest user to use(or see) the Virtualbox. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998298/give-virtualbox-access-to-specific-users-only). But it doesn't seems to be working for me. I can still find and use VirtualBox under the ***Show Applications***, when logged in as a **Guest** User.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is a way to do achieve what you want with AppArmor
Since i cant find an easy way to do it, id say that you can 'play' with files permissions.

1. Create a group or simply use the built-in vboxusers
2. Change ownership of virtualbox files and launcher(s)
3. Change perms of virtualbox files
4. Add you permitted user(s) to the group created in (1)

``

```
# 1 # Create a group
sudo addgroup vboxpermitted
# add current user to the new group
useradd -g vboxpermitted $USER

# 2 # Change ownership
sudo chown -R root:vboxpermitted /usr/lib/virtualbox/*
sudo chown root:voxpermitted /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop

# 3 # Customize execute rights (not for all, but for group)
find /usr/lib/virtualbox/ -type f -exec sudo chmod a-x {} \;
chmod 640 /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop

# 4 # Add permitted user(s) to new group
adduser -g vboxpermitted <username>
```