# How can I mv files from another user to my Home folder (knowing the password of the other user)?

Tags: permissions, cp

Suppose I am logged in as user A on a PC. On the same PC there is another user B. I want to move certain files from user's B home folder to A's home folder. Note that neither A nor B are sudo. However, I know the password of both users. What can I do?

PD: I know a workaround using `scp` (and then `rm` the source files). However that has the downside of *copying* the files, which can be *very* slow for large files, while `mv` would be instantaneous because it is a local operation. I want a solution that actually moves the files.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/291501/share-a-folder-between-two-local-users

Comment: @user68186 The question you link has a solution that requires a graphic interface. I am doing this at a remote server, that doesn't have GUI. How can I do it from the terminal? Also, remember I'm not sudo.

Comment: With only one `mv` per file?

Comment: @A.B. I'm not sure I understand your question.  To me it is not important how many times you call `mv`. As long as it is faster than a copy.

Comment: Are the users in the same group? does the file need to change user and group to the new user?

Comment: cp is safer if you aren't sure exactly what you are doing. As always, backup before blindly following advice that may be faulty.

Comment: without sudo? Is there a directory that both user A and user B have read/write access to? Do you have access to a flash/external drive?

Comment: There is no directory where both A and B can r/w. But maybe I can create one, inside A's home or B's home? How would I do that with the terminal (and without sudo)?

Answer (score 1):

## A cannot directly move a folder from B's home folder without sudo

**So we will create a folder with lowered security in B's home**

1. Login as B and type:

   b@remote_computer:~$ mkdir tobemoved

This will create a folder `/home/b/tobemoved`

**Move whatever files and folder you want to move inside this
    folder**

For example if you want to move a file from the `Documents` folder:

```
b@remote_computer:~$ mv ~/Documents/somefile ~/tobemoved/
```

This will also work if you want to move `somefolder` instead of `somefile`.

**Lower the read write delete permission for everything within the folder
   `tobemoved`**

```
b@remote_computer:~$ chmod -R 777 tobemoved
```

*Note: now anyone with an account in this computer can read, copy, delete and modify the files in this folder!*

**Log out and log back in as A**

This is so that you want to move B's files to A's home

**Create a folder to keep the files from B**

```
a@remote_computer:~$ mkdir a_folder_to_keep_files_from_b
```

**Move the files**

```
a@remote_computer:~$ mv /home/b/tobemoved /home/a/a_folder_to_keep_files_from_b/
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No way without `sudo`.

1. trial, failure – `sudo`

   ```
   su B
   # the command below works only with sudo
   sudo chown A:A /home/B/<your_file_name>
   su -c A 'mv /home/B/<your_file_name> /home/A/'
   ```
2. trial, failure – multiple `mv` and wrong ownership `<your_file_name>`

   ```
   su A
   mkdir incoming
   chmod 777 incoming
   su B
   mv /home/B/<your_file_name> /home/A/incoming
   su A
   mv /home/A/incoming/<your_file_name> /home/A/<your_final_target>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without super user access unless you can circumvent permissions somehow, whether by having an interim directory that both users have r/w access to or using a FAT formatted external device (requiring physical access). If you have physical access to the hardware you can do whatever you want of course. Since you have access to both accounts you could transfer the files via an ftp server or a file sharing service.

Comment: Can I create somehow a directory where both users have r/w access? Like sharing?

Comment: That depends on how securely the system is set up, but I would assume no or you wouldn't have this question. You can create whatever you want in your own home directory and same for the other user, however you need to be able to traverse the other users directory which is beyond your ability to change without super user access. Ask the administrator or gain physical access to the machine.

Comment: I know the passwords for both users A and B. So I can login either of them as required. Wouldn't that help?

Comment: The consensus appears to be no. Did you try user68186 answer?