# Ubuntu, messed up default group ownership

Tags: permissions, chown

I've setup `btsync` on my pc and in order for it to access the folder I wanted to sync I had to set it's owner and group to btsync. I did so by running `sudo chown -R btsync:btsync ~/sync`. Or at least, I attempted that but I typo'd it an accidentally set `~`'s group and owner to `btsync`.

I tried to fix it by running `sudo chown -R paul:paul ~` to fix the mess I made, but I keep seeing files group getting changed randomly to btsync. For example:

```
~$ ll | grep btsync
-rw-r--r--  1 paul   btsync      25 Feb 17 20:39 .dmrc
drwxrwxrwx  7 btsync btsync    4096 Feb 17 20:21 sync/
-rw-------  1 paul   btsync     711 Feb 17 20:39 .xsession-errors
```

The `sync` folder is supposed to be `btsync:btsync`, but the others keep reverting. Additionally when I install programs through the software-center that install to my home directory. They appear to be installing with the `:btsync` group, where they should be `:paul`. (For example when I install `vidalia`.)

Can anyone help me fix whatever this issue is? Thanks to all in advance.

UPDATE: I don't know if this is necessary information, but I'm runing ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring anything else unforeseen at this time, I believe I solved my issue. I installed `gnome-system-tools` and found out that I accidentally changed my user's default group to `:btsync`. By using `gnome-system-tools` I was able to revert my mistake and change my default group back to `:paul`.

See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/66727/177551) for more usage