# Ubuntu 14.10 create new user password change button disabled

Tags: users, user-management, 14.10

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 (AMD64) to my desktop this evening. Everything works fine as in the versions before. Now I started to create some more users. I can only activate them if I choose to not set any password for them. The button to apply the changes is disabled as long as I try to set a password.

I tried to restart the computer, set a password with `passwd`, deleted and recreated the user. I tried to first activate the user without a password and set it later on. Nothing helped. The button keeps disabled if I try to set a password (tried weak, empty and strong passwords, used the visible and hidden option for the password textfields). Seems to be a bug or it is not intuitive...

Anyway, does anybody know a workaround, to activate password usage for a specific user (config file) after setting the password using `passwd`?

Answer (score 2):

This is how to create a new user from `unity-control-center user-accounts` (search for **User Accounts** in Dash):

1. From an administrator account **unlock** settings (click on **Unlock** to enter password). Then add a user with <kbd>**+**</kbd>):

   [image]
2. Enter username:

   [image]
3. Enter password dialog by clicking on *Password: Account disabled*:

   [image]
4. Choose a [strong password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords) for the user.

   [image]
   Shown here is the dialog when entering a weak password, which is **not allowed**.
5. Repeat the password (without typing error!):

   [image]
6. Only if steps 4. and 5. are correct we will be able to <kbd>Change</kbd> the password to activate the new account.

Comment: Worth to take a look to this close question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I deleted the user from the group nopasswdlogin:

```
sudo gpasswd -d *username* nopasswdlogin
```

I still don't know how to fix this via GUI.