# I can't create a group for my users how do i do it?

Tags: users, user-management, groups

How do i create a group for users i have already created on Ubuntu? I have tried several things but it won't work.

Comment: Follow the instructions in this answer to do it the GUI way: http://askubuntu.com/a/66727/364819

Answer (score 2):

At the terminal, you can create a new group using

```
sudo groupadd GroupName
```

and then you can add a user using

```
sudo useradd -G GroupName UserName
```