# User Groups and Advanced Settings in 15.04

Tags: users, gui, settings, 15.04, groups

Ubuntu used to allow me to change user's groups and advanced settings within the "User Settings" GUI. These options are gone now in 15.04. Where do I go to find these settings?

(Using the command line is not an option for my use cases.)

This is the old dialog with "Manage Groups" and "Advanced Settings" buttons.
[image: The old interface]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

[How to manage users and groups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)