# Where is 'Users and Groups' in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, users, unity-dash, groups

'Users and Groups' seems to have disappeared in Ubuntu 15.10

Now I can only see 'User Accounts' from the dash

If you want to use the gnome-system-tools, then you have to run users-admin from the cmd line

Would it not make more sense to give the tool the same name as used in the apt-get install, i.e. to run gnome-system-tools, you type gnome-system-tools at the cmd line or in the dash?

rather than having to scour the interwebs to find that the name of the exe is users-admin

Or possibly typing gnome-system-tools in the dash could suggest you try users-admin?

I also note that typing users-admin in the dash doesn't bring back any suggestions

Am I missing something here, or does this all seem unreasonably tricky?

Comment: Have you seen the answer posted here?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/616042/user-groups-and-advanced-settings-in-15-04

Comment: thanks - i got there in the end, i just find the package name to exe name leap for some of these things is crazy - there must be a more logical way of discovering the name of the exe installed by a package other than scouring interweb discussion fora?

Comment: users-admin is one of 4 binaries in the gnome-system-tools package. So no reason to do as you suggested. If you want to know what's in a package there are various cli solutions or just install synaptic, highlight an installed package > properties > installed files. The same is somewhat true if you know a binary name but need to find the package, some cli solutions or just go to this page, ect. http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: do you know what the simplest cli solution might be?

Comment: I found this that takes me from a file to its package (http://superuser.com/questions/146875/command-to-find-the-source-package-of-a-binary), but struggling to find how to do the opposite, i.e. package to its files

Comment: scratch that, its dpkg-query -L <package_name>