# How do you create new users with passwords and set their permissions in SSH?

Tags: server, ssh

Want to create users and set least privilege needed for all users. How can I set permissions and make sure users can only access their own files and also create an admin that can access all? Is admin the same as root?

Comment: Um, how to do that in SSH ? same as [any other way on linux](http://askubuntu.com/q/66718/295286), you create it and then shove into appropriate group. For regular user, no other group is necessary. Admin is nothing more than user with `sudo` access (sudo group), which effectively lets you do `root` tasks with your own account and password.

Answer (score 0):

The root is admin
If you are talking about Ubuntu , then you need not to worry , the files in your home folder cannot be accessed by anyone else . You can create a new user by the command

```
useradd <username>
```

You can set password for the user using the command

```
Passwd <username>
```

Then enter the password.

By default, users have minimum permission, and can access nothing but  their own files , unless given root priviledge.
Hope this helps