# What are the types of user group in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, root, users, groups

I want to know how groups work in Linux. In windows users that belong to admin group can have access to everything. So I want to know how to create a user and add that user in Root group or whichever group has access to everything in Linux.

Comment: Also check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

In the terminal, type the following command, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME
```

This will create a new user (replace `USERNAME` with the new user's username). It will ask you to enter a password for the new user, as well as a bunch of other optional information (full name, phone number, etc). Now, add that user to the `sudo` group:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME sudo
```

(again, replace `USERNAME` with the new user's username). This will allow the new user to run any command as root by typing:

```
sudo COMMAND
```

in the terminal, and then entering the new user's password.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you do not need to do that. If you type `id` you can see what groups you are in:

```
$ id
uid=1000(zanna) gid=1000(zanna) 
groups=1000(zanna),4(adm),7(lp),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),113(lpadmin),129(sambashare),1001(unicorns)
```

Oh look I am in a group called `sudo`... that means I am allowed to issue commands as the superuser... which commands am I allowed to use in that way?

```
$ sudo -l
User zanna may run the following commands on monster:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

That's probably enough privileges :)

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups) a good question about managing users and groups in Ubuntu as pointed out by Anwar Shah. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups) also gives insight.