# Cannot read file even I'm in same group

Tags: permissions

Here is the case:

```
adduser pravdomil www-data
adduser tana www-data
touch                     /home/test.txt
chown pravdomil:pravdomil /home/test.txt
chmod 440                 /home/test.txt
reboot
runuser -l tana -c 'cat   /home/test.txt'
```

Produces `cat: /home/test.txt: Permission denied` on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

The file is readable by group and if two users is in the same group (and one is the owner of file) both should have read access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage users and groups?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, user `tana` is not member of group `pravdomil`. With `chown pravdomil:pravdomil` you set user `pravdomil` and group `pravdomil` as owner of `/home/test.txt`.

Try with `chown pravdomil:www-data /home/test.txt`.