# Ubuntu Security Group

Tags: security, 17.04

How I can check Ubuntu server is in a security group that accepts inbound connections to specific IP address x.x.x.x  ?

I am trying to use conjure-up to deploy kubernetes,

1. I have MAAS Installed with 2 Nodes (both ready)
2. I installed Conjure-up
3. I Run conjure-up kubernetes, then used MAAS as a cloud
4. After boot strapping one of the nodes and installing OS
5. The porcess stuck and console shows the Attempting to connect to x.x.x.x:22
6. x.x.x.x is the nodes is already up and running from step 4
7. All setting is working under System proxy

After search for solution I found this:

When prompted, deploy all five remaining items.  When you see "Juju Controller is initializing. Please wait."  You may observe a delay on the step that says

> Attempting to connect to x.x.x.x:22"  You may want to make sure your
>   Ubuntu server is in a security group that accepts inbound connections
>   to the IP address x.x.x.x.

Comment: Monitor your traffic with snort, wireshark, or from your router I suppose. We need a lot more details of your networks architecture and configuration of your firewall to give any meaningful answer.

Comment: The Main question is how can I edit "Ubuntu Security Group"? Is there any specific location for Security Group? like /etc/security/....

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about. https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups ?

Comment: I am trying to use conjure-up to deploy kubernetes, then I got stuck in this step:     .  When prompted, deploy all five remaining items.  When you see "Juju Controller is initializing. Please wait."  You may observe a delay on the step that says "Attempting to connect to x.x.x.x:22"  You may want to make sure your Ubuntu server is in a security group that accepts inbound connections to the IP address x.x.x.x.

Comment: What tutorial are you following ? Sounds as if you need to configure your server and network to allow connections. We really can not understand what you are doing.

Comment: I up-dated the question with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in juju 2.0.2.

1. Installed snap juju
2. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
3. sudo apt update
4. sudo apt install juju

Now with juju 2.2.2 : it worked!