# Does Kubuntu have a GUI user and group manager?

Tags: kubuntu, users, groups

In kubuntu 18.04 the User Manager in Settings can add and delete users, but that's about it.

I need to modify groups and users so seldomly that I spend more time reading `man` pages and finding the commands than actually doing the changes!

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-using-gui) addresses the question for gnome (if it is still relevant  after 10 years or so) but I would prefer a KDE solution. Is there one?

Comment: Seems like a possible XY Question. What is the actual problem you are encountering that leads to you believe a "*GUI user and group manager*" is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after further digging...

There used to be KUser which did exactly what I was after, but it is no longer maintained.

But the standard repositories contain lxqt-admin-user which does the job instead. To install: `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lxqt-admin`. If you don't use `--no-install-recommends` it will install several 10s of Mb of stuff instead of a couple of hundred of kb, but still works ok.

Thanks to https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/general/documentation/knowledge-base/67127-user-management-2018