# Missing user management settings on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, system-settings

User management settings are missing in my Xubuntu installation.
As described in [Xubuntu documentation](https://docs.xubuntu.org/current/user/C/administrative-tasks.html) it should be under *Users and Groups* but I don't have this item.

I'm using Xubuntu 22.04 and I did a "minimal installation". I imagine this is why this option is missing.

How can I add user management to Xfce in this case?

[image: All settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software you are looking for is called "users-admin" and resides in the "gnome-system-tools" package.
Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/174091/906933) for additional infos.

Since this package is not really necessary it is - wisely - not included in the "minimal setup"